# Error in deploying sandbox to production in salesforce

Tags: object, deployment, ant, salesforce, lookup

I am deploying my project from sandbox to production. And i am using "ANT" tool for deploying. But it is giving me error as given below:

> Error: objects/Form__c.object(144,13):field integrity exception:
>   unknown (must specify either cascade delete or restrict delete for
>   required lookup foreign key)

Can anybody help me please.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi Can you provide more detail about the Form object - specifically around line 144?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto line no 144 of your object Form__c there will be a Lookup Field , in that field remove the 'Required' Tag , remove that tag completed and start your ant deploying again.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an API version mismatch thing. If I recall correctly ability to reparent master-detail relationships and to mark lookups as required on DB level instead of layout level was introduced in summer'12. Your XML file is coming from sandbox without this feature so SF is complaining at the missing tags.

See [release notes](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer12_release_notes.pdf) (pages 183-184), though they don't really mention the metadata changes...